# Matrix and determinant inequality

Tags: matrices, inequality, determinant

Let $A \in M_n {(\mathbb{R})} $ such that $A+A^T=2I_n$.
Prove that $\det(A)\geq 1 $.
I find out the form of $A$ and, respectively, its determinant, but i can not prove that it is bigger than 1, any ideas?

Comment: I made a mistake, i edited the question.

Comment: You are trying to say something about the determinant and are given information about the sum of two matrices. Are you familiar with any facts about determinants that involve the sum of two matrices?

Comment: It would help if you would say what you found out about (the form of) the determinant.

Comment: you can ping me once the contest is over. (With documentation that it is.)